# Is `Properties` still used for loading configuration of JDBC from a file?

Tags: java, jdbc, properties

I heard that [`Properties` is legacy in Java.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21086364/156458)

Is `Properties` still used for [load configuration of JDBC from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785022/why-is-jdbc-dynamically-loaded-instead-of-imported?noredirect=1#comment88588696_50785068) as in an [an old reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4085484/156458)?

Without `Properties`, how can we do the same? By normal file-read functions and manually parse the files?

> You can save you `db.properties` file to an external fixed location,
>   and access it for later to retrieve your connection properties:
>
> ```java
> Properties props = new Properties();
> FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/external/configuration/dir/db.properties");
> props.load(in);
> in.close();
>
> String driver = props.getProperty("jdbc.driver");
> if (driver != null) {
>     Class.forName(driver) ;
> }
>
> String url = props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
> String username = props.getProperty("jdbc.username");
> String password = props.getProperty("jdbc.password");
>
> Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
> ```
>
> Then, on every environment you can have a different copy of your
>   database settings, without having to change your application file
>   (JAR, ER, or whatever).
>
> Sample database connection properties file:
>
> ```ruby
> # Oracle DB properties
> #jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
> #jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1571:MyDbSID
> #jdbc.username=root
> #jdbc.password=admin
>
> # MySQL DB properties
> jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
> jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDbName
> jdbc.username=root
> jdbc.password=admin
> ```

Comment: What are you asking? Or do you just want opinions?

Comment: Don't believe everything you read on the Internet. There is *not one word* in the [Javadoc for `java.util.Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) about it being 'legacy'. In fact, as @BrianRoach points out in a comment on your linked question, there is no such thing as a 'legacy class' in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. At least in my organization, many configurations (not just database conf) are still loaded from properties files, which is perfectly normal and working well. I think it's only legacy in the sense that as a container, the `Properties` class came out before the introduction of the Java Collections Framework, like `Vector` and `Hashtable`.

On the other hand, alternatives like `YAML` and `JSON` are getting more popular. Probably because it's can become repetitive to describe an object with fields in a properties file.

```
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDbName
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=admin
```

While the same configuration in `YAML` would be more concise and readable(?).

```
jdbc:
  driver: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url: "mysql://localhost:3306/MyDB"
  username: "root"
  password: ""
```

Comment: There is a difference between the properties file format (which is either a flat-file or XML), and the `Properties` object. It would be possible (and solutions exist) that read a YAML file and produce a `Properties` object.